# Live Distros: UBCD boot Deft, Caine, and Tails from Custom Menu

Tags: linux, livecd, initramfs, bootable

I'm building my own UBCD and I'm using dual layer to fit 7.5Gigs

---

Useful resources for UBCD customization:

- [The SYSLINUX Project](http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/The_SYSLINUX_Project)
- [UBCD Customize](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/customize.html)
- [Casper Man Page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man7/casper.7.html)
- [Live Boot Man Page](http://live.debian.net/manpages/current/en/html/live-boot.7.html)

---

Here's my `custom.cfg` file.

```
MENU INCLUDE /ubcd/menus/syslinux/defaults.cfg
UI menu.c32

LABEL -
MENU LABEL ..
CONFIG /ubcd/menus/syslinux/main.cfg

LABEL -
MENU LABEL Caine 5.0 January 17th, 2014
TEXT HELP
 Read only system forensics. 64bit system required.
ENDTEXT
LINUX /ubcd/custom/caine/casper/vmlinuz
INITRD /ubcd/custom/caine/casper/initrd.gz
APPEND boot=casper splash

LABEL -
MENU LABEL Deft 8.1 April 10th, 2014
TEXT HELP
 Digital Evidence & Forensics Toolkit. 64bit system required.
ENDTEXT
LINUX /ubcd/custom/deft/casper/vmlinuz
INITRD /ubcd/custom/deft/casper/initrd.lz
APPEND file=/ubcd/custom/deft/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubcd/custom/deft.iso splash --

LABEL -
MENU LABEL SpinRite
TEXT HELP
 Repair damaged Hard Drives with Steve Gibson's SpinRite.
ENDTEXT
LINUX /boot/syslinux/memdisk
INITRD /ubcd/custom/spinrite.iso
APPEND iso raw 

LABEL -
MENU LABEL Tails 1.0.1 June 10th, 2014
TEXT HELP
 The Amnesic Incognito Live System. i386
ENDTEXT
LINUX /ubcd/custom/tails/live/vmlinuz
INITRD /ubcd/custom/tails/live/initrd.img
APPEND boot=live config live-media=removable nopersistent noprompt timezone=Etc/UTC block.events_dfl_poll_msecs=1000 splash noautologin module=Tails iso-scan/filename=/ubcd/custom/tails.iso

LABEL -
MENU LABEL Tails (failsafe) 1.0.1 June 10th, 2014
TEXT HELP
 The Amnesic Incognito Live System. i386
ENDTEXT
LINUX /ubcd/custom/tails/live/vmlinuz
INITRD /ubcd/custom/tails/live/initrd.img
APPEND boot=live config live-media=removable nopersistent noprompt timezone=Etc/UTC block.events_dfl_poll_msecs=1000 splash noautologin module=Tails noapic noapm nodma nomce nolapic nomodeset nosmp vga=normal iso-scan/filename=/ubcd/custom/tails.iso

LABEL -
MENU LABEL Tails 1.0.1 64bit June 10th, 2014
TEXT HELP
 The Amnesic Incognito Live System. amd64
ENDTEXT
LINUX /ubcd/custom/tails/live/vmlinuz2
INITRD /ubcd/custom/tails/live/initrd2.img
APPEND boot=live config live-media=removable nopersistent noprompt timezone=Etc/UTC block.events_dfl_poll_msecs=1000 splash noautologin module=Tails iso-scan/filename=/ubcd/custom/tails.iso

LABEL -
MENU LABEL Tails 1.0.1 64bit (failsafe) June 10th, 2014
TEXT HELP
 The Amnesic Incognito Live System. amd64
ENDTEXT
LINUX /ubcd/custom/tails/live/vmlinuz2
INITRD /ubcd/custom/tails/live/initrd2.img
APPEND boot=live config live-media=removable nopersistent noprompt timezone=Etc/UTC block.events_dfl_poll_msecs=1000 splash noautologin module=Tails noapic noapm nodma nomce nolapic nomodeset nosmp vga=normal iso-scan/filename=/ubcd/custom/tails.iso

LABEL -
MENU LABEL Ubuntu Rescue Remix 12.04 April 26th, 2012
TEXT HELP
 Ubuntu system rescue utility disc.
ENDTEXT
LINUX /ubcd/custom/urr/casper/vmlinuz
INITRD /ubcd/custom/urr/casper/initrd.gz
APPEND boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubcd/custom/urr.iso splash --
```

SpinRite works and Ubuntu Rescue works with some keyboard recognition error noise (but keyboard entry works fine.)  Side note: Ubuntu Rescue also works with the options `APPEND iso raw`, but then it loads the entire iso image into memory before booting.

Caine, Deft, and Tails all don't find a live image to boot.  Caine gets to some sort of sys mem prompt but keyboard input does nothing.  Deft and tails get to a similar prompt initramfs.  Both without the live image found, one of them doesn't respond to the keyboard and the other doesn't recognize it.

Basically I need to boot with the live images.  Here's a tree of the directory structure under /ubcd/custom (with the Caine windows files cut out)

```
.
├── caine
│   ├── autorun.inf
│   ├── boot.catalog
│   ├── casper
│   │   ├── filesystem.squashfs
│   │   ├── initrd.gz
│   │   └── vmlinuz
│   ├── EFI
│   │   └── BOOT
│   │       ├── BOOTx64.EFI
│   │       └── grubx64.efi
│   ├── isolinux
│   │   ├── isolinux.bin
│   │   ├── isolinux.cfg
│   │   ├── splash.png
│   │   └── vesamenu.c32
│   ├── ldlinux.sys
│   ├── syslinux.cfg
│   └── UFO.dat
├── custom.cfg
├── custom.lst
├── deft
│   ├── casper
│   │   ├── initrd.lz
│   │   └── vmlinuz
│   └── preseed
│       ├── cli.seed
│       └── lubuntu.seed
├── deft.iso
├── spinrite.iso
├── tails
│   └── live
│       ├── initrd2.img
│       ├── initrd.img
│       ├── vmlinuz
│       └── vmlinuz2
├── tails.iso
├── urr
│   └── casper
│       ├── initrd.gz
│       └── vmlinuz
└── urr.iso
```

I extracted out the vmlinuz and initrd files from the ISOs but tried to keep and mount the existing ISOs just like the working Ubuntu example.

So the lines in the config are the LINUX/INITRD/APPEND lines for Caine, Deft, and Tails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Tails**
pass the argument `findiso` to  kernel as

> findiso=/path/to/ISO boot=live config live-media=removable nopersistent noprompt quiet timezone=Etc/UTC block.events_dfl_poll_msecs=1000 splash nox11autologin module=Tails quiet

## update

If you extract the content of ISO's to respective folders then they can be booted with the boot argument **live-media-path**.

Assuming ISO's are unpacked to `/multiboot/OSname`, where OSname is the name of the corresponding OS as given below.  The following code is used by [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com)

> # Simple Menu Created by Lance http://www.pendrivelinux.com for YUMI - (Your USB Multiboot Installer)

caine

> label live
>     menu label live - boot the Live System
>     kernel /multiboot/caine/casper/vmlinuz
>     append cdrom-detect/try-usb=true noprompt live-media-path=/multiboot/caine/casper/ file=/cdrom/preseed/custom.seed boot=casper initrd=/multiboot/caine/casper/initrd.gz quiet splash --

deft

> menu label ^DEFT Linux LIVE
>     kernel /multiboot/deft/casper/vmlinuz
>     append cdrom-detect/try-usb=true noprompt floppy.allowed_drive_mask=0 ignore_uuid live-media-path=/multiboot/deft/casper file=/multiboot/deft/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/multiboot/deft/casper/initrd.lz --

tails

> menu label ^Run T(A)ILS (Anonymous Browsing)
>    kernel /multiboot/tails/live/vmlinuz
>    append timezone=America/Detroit initrd=/multiboot/tails/live/initrd.img boot=live config live-media=removable live-media-path=/multiboot/tails/live nopersistent noprompt quiet block.events_dfl_poll_msecs=1000 splash nox11autologin quiet

<s>code</s>

Comment: Do you have any insight on the changes you're showing me as to what will make this work?  What's the difference that matters?

Answer (score 0):

I'm accepting totti's answer.  Since I didn't have a preseed file for Caine I downloaded the default for Ubuntu 14.04 https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt and per ubuntu's recomendation I put it in the root folder of UBCD.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/preseed-using.html

I've extracted all 3 distros into their respective folders in `/ubcd/custom` and I have deleted the ISO files.

Here's my final config for all to see.

```
MENU INCLUDE /ubcd/menus/syslinux/defaults.cfg
UI menu.c32

LABEL -
MENU LABEL ..
CONFIG /ubcd/menus/syslinux/main.cfg

LABEL -
MENU LABEL Caine 5.0 January 17th, 2014
TEXT HELP
 Read only system forensics. 64bit system required.
ENDTEXT
KERNEL /ubcd/custom/caine/casper/vmlinuz
INITRD /ubcd/custom/caine/casper/initrd.gz
APPEND cdrom-detect/try-usb=true noprompt nopersistent live-media-path=/ubcd/custom/caine/casper/ file=/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --

LABEL -
MENU LABEL Deft 8.1 April 10th, 2014
TEXT HELP
 Digital Evidence & Forensics Toolkit. 64bit system required.
ENDTEXT
KERNEL /ubcd/custom/deft/casper/vmlinuz
INITRD /ubcd/custom/deft/casper/initrd.lz
APPEND cdrom-detect/try-usb=true noprompt nopersistent floppy.allowed_drive_mask=0 ignore_uuid live-media-path=/ubcd/custom/deft/casper file=/ubcd/custom/deft/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --

LABEL -
MENU LABEL SpinRite
TEXT HELP
 Repair damaged Hard Drives with Steve Gibson's SpinRite.
ENDTEXT
LINUX /boot/syslinux/memdisk
INITRD /ubcd/custom/spinrite.iso
APPEND iso raw 

LABEL -
MENU LABEL Tails 1.0.1 June 10th, 2014
TEXT HELP
 The Amnesic Incognito Live System. i386
ENDTEXT
KERNEL /ubcd/custom/tails/live/vmlinuz
INITRD /ubcd/custom/tails/live/initrd.img
APPEND timezone=America/Detroit boot=live config live-media=removable live-media-path=/ubcd/custom/tails/live nopersistent noprompt block.events_dfl_poll_msecs=1000 splash nox11autologin quiet splash

LABEL -
MENU LABEL Tails 1.0.1 64bit June 10th, 2014
TEXT HELP
 The Amnesic Incognito Live System. amd64
ENDTEXT
KERNEL /ubcd/custom/tails/live/vmlinuz2
INITRD /ubcd/custom/tails/live/initrd2.img
APPEND timezone=America/Detroit boot=live config live-media=removable live-media-path=/ubcd/custom/tails/live nopersistent noprompt block.events_dfl_poll_msecs=1000 splash nox11autologin quiet splash

LABEL -
MENU LABEL Ubuntu Rescue Remix 12.04 April 26th, 2012
TEXT HELP
 Ubuntu system rescue utility disc.
ENDTEXT
LINUX /ubcd/custom/urr/casper/vmlinuz
INITRD /ubcd/custom/urr/casper/initrd.gz
APPEND root=/ubcd/custom boot=casper findiso=/ubcd/custom/urr.iso quiet splash --
```

And everything works now!